# How to export SVG with Chinese characters to PNG using Inkscape?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unicode, svg, inkscape

When trying to export an SVG file with Chinese characters to PNG using Inkscape, the Chinese characters disappear. I use this command in Ubuntu:

```
inkscape /root/21.svg -e /root/1.png
```

Comment: Please show us the simplest SVG file which demonstrates the problem, and the corresponding .PNG file. Also, please tell us with which font you are formatting the Chinese characters.

Comment: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13269 check it for png and svg info.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating another svg file and adding a simple text by example: 汉语 / 汉语

**My svg:**

[image]

**My command:**

```
inkscape Desktop/chinese.svg -e Desktop/test.png
```

**My result:**

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, but an example showing that it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I had no choice, it is great to make a comment. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: I use command line in linux.I think I don't install the right font in my linux server,But I don't know how to install font. thank.

Comment: I asked a question at here http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13269 too.